# Error: java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm stucked with this problem, I don't know what's wrong with my code, please help me. I got `error java.lang.nullpointerexception` on this code:

```
List<DataPoint> listPoints;
if((listPoints = hashMap.get(h)) == null) {
    listPoints = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    DataPoint point = new DataPoint((int)songId, i);
    listPoints.add(point);
    hashMap.put(h, listPoints);
}
```

Comment: Post logcat so where know which line is giving `NPE`. There's a good chance that `hashMap` is `null`

Comment: maybe `hashMap` is not initialized ?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code and what line is actually throwing the NullPointer?

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading HashMap from other thread it might be still null at the point of using it. Also h may be null too. A little bit more detail will be good

Answer (score 0):

```
if((listPoints = hashMap.get(h)) == null)
{
    listPoints = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    DataPoint point = new DataPoint((int)songId, i);
    listPoints.add(point);
    hashMap.put(h, listPoints);
}
```

From that snippet, the only lines you'd be getting `NullPointerException` is in the `hashMap.get()` and `hashMap.put()` calls. My bet is that `hashMap` was not initialized and hence is `null`. So, when you call `hashMap.get()`, you get your exception.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the implementation of HashMap (e.g. ConcurrentHashMap) you are using does not accept null keys - if h is null then this would cause a NullPointerException.